# Find biggest and smallest values of an array using loops

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, arm64, armv8

I have the following code already written and everything should be good. It suppose to find biggest and smallest values in array of size 4 using loop.

I got the loops setup and everything except my output is not correct. I have a bug in line 46 that when load the array the value into register X11 I get big weird number and causes the whole calculations to be wrong.

Please see if you can suggests a fix in this code.

```
//X0 Array, X17 number of runs, X11 Biggest, X12 Smallest

ADR X0,v
LDR X17,=4
LDR X11,[X0],#3
MOV X12,X11
loop:
    **LDR X11,[X0],#3 //Line 46**
    //LSL X11,X0,#3
    CMP X12,X11
    BLT loop1
    SUB X17,X17,#1
    CMP X17,#1
    BEQ exit
    BGT loop
loop1:
    MOV X12,X11
    SUB X17,X17,#1
    CMP X17,#1
    BEQ exit
    BGT loop
```

I'm using the DS-5 IDE, in case that matters.

Comment: What is `v`? Make sure it's 64 bit integers not 32.

Comment: BTW, if you make counter equal 3 (number of actual iterations) `LDR X17,=(4-1)`, than instead of `SUB X17,X17,#1; CMP X17,#1; BGT loop` you could use  `SUB X17,X17,#1; CBNZ loop`

Comment: Oh I see thanks, will try!

Comment: @user3124812: IIRC, `cbnz` can only jump forwards.  But you can use `subs x17, x17, #1` / `bne loop` to jump backwards on the flags result of SUBS.

Comment: Also note, AArch64 has handy instructions like `csel` to select one of two registers based on a condition.  Actually easier to use than jumping over a `mov` to update your min and max candidates.  (AArch64 also has SIMD integer min and max instructions, which might even be available for a single 64-bit integer in the bottom of a 16-byte vector.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: `cbnz` can jump backwards or forwards, a good long ways.  It takes a sign-extended 19-bit displacement.

Comment: @PeterCordes: The SIMD `smax` and `smaxv` unfortunately don't appear to support the `2D` arrangement so we can't use them on 64-bit values, at least not in a straightforward way.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Oh good, I guess I was thinking of the ARM Thumb version.  Is there any reason to prefer cbnz over using subs/bne flags?  I guess if you want to keep flags unmodified.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Good question. I don't really know whether there'd be a performance difference, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LDR X11,[X0],#3`

Reading 64bit values (Xregister), and post-incrementing by `#3`?
I have a great suspicions that 3Bytes != 64bit.

Comment: ‍♂️, ‍♂️, ‍♂️, ‍♂️, ‍♂️
You both are %100 correct. I was suppose to use #8. life savor thanks!